# Add custom parameters to JSON API search query?

Tags: search, plugin-json-api

I am using [JSON API plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/) to query wordpress from a mobile app.

Currently I have a theme on my wordpress site which works as a directory returning "near me" results when a search is made. This is done using a custom search function builtin in the theme.

The function uses custom parameters to get the `lat/lon` of the user and compare it to the lat/lon of each place in the wp database to sort results by distance.

The issue I am having is that when I run the `get_search_results` method from the `JSON API plugin` the custom parameters are ignored.

Does anyone know if there is anyway I can extend the plugin to return the same results the theme is returning when performing a search.

The plugin seems to have a way to extend controllers, but I can't seem to get my head around on how to use that to customize the search query.

Any tip putting me in the right direction will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Plugins are off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is better that you switch to the [current beta, version 2](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API), publish on github. This version is much better in possibilities and performance.

In this version it is possible that you get a result for the search term, Iike `GET /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?s=awesome`.

Comment: Hi! thanks, per the docs it looks similar to v1 for the search method. It seems there is a way to create a custom method which will accept my custom parameters, but I can't find a way. I will keep digging. Thanks again.

Comment: You can enhance the endpoints. The WP API have filter, like `json_prepare_{type}`, for this requirement. See in the documentation or also in my [github account](https://github.com/search?q=user%3Abueltge+rest) for examples, currently two repos.

Comment: Thanks, thay definetely will work. I have to learn how to implement it with my code, but it looks like what I need. Thanks a lot.